# Add more hadoop nodes does not improve Nutch Crawling speed

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, nutch

I'm Crawling web pages with Apache Nutch(1.18 version).

I Thought that adding more hadoop nodes makes Nutch crawl web pages more fast.

However, It doesn't. There are almost no differences when crawling with 3 datanodes and 5 datanodes.

I've added --num-fetchers parameter(value is 5, because the number of my hadoop datanodes is 5) too.

please help me to find what's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a broad web crawl covering many web sites (hosts / domains) will profit from adding more Hadoop nodes. If only a small number of sites is crawled, parallelization will not make Nutch faster. Nutch configured to behave polite by default and does not access a single site in parallel and also waits between successive fetches from the same site.

But there are ways to make Nutch crawl a single site faster.

1. to make a single fetcher task faster (and more aggressively fetching from a single host (or domain depending on the value of [partition.url.mode](https://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.18/resources/nutch-default.xml#partition.url.mode)) the following configuration properties need to be adapted: `fetcher.server.delay`, `fetcher.threads.per.queue` and maybe other fetcher properties.
2. to allow more fetcher tasks (Hadoop nodes) crawl the same web site in parallel, [URLPartitioner's getPartition method](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/6c02da053d8ce65e0283a144ab59586e563608b8/src/java/org/apache/nutch/crawl/URLPartitioner.java#L75) needs to be modified, see [this discussion](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r3a4203d450bd903b88810a86e93ab30e59462609c23349df90e31bb9%40%3Cuser.nutch.apache.org%3E).

Be aware that making Nutch more aggressive without consent will probably result in complaints by the admins of the crawled web sites and increases the likelihood to get blocked!

Comment: Detailed answer, appreciate it.